# Can't install MongoDB with Ansible on Debian 10

Tags: mongodb, azure, ansible, debian

I'm trying to write an Ansible playbook for a virtual machine in Azure with Debian 10 but when I install MongoDB I got this error `apt cache update failed`. I'm using **Ansible 2.9.2 and Python 3.7.**. 
The complete trace of the error is:

The full traceback is:

```
  File "/tmp/ansible_apt_repository_payload_6nwou6ke/ansible_apt_repository_payload.zip/ansible/modules/packaging/os/apt_repository.py", line 548, in main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 562, in update
    raise FetchFailedException(e)

fatal: [debian10]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "codename": null,
            "filename": null,
            "install_python_apt": true,
            "mode": null,
            "repo": "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist 10gen",
            "state": "present",
            "update_cache": true,
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "apt cache update failed"
}
```

I've used galaxy roles and I've tried it following many tutorials but I can't solve it. Anyone can help?

Comment: Have you tried to run same command manually on your server: `sudo apt update` ? You could get more details about the error from it. Alternatively, you can find some hints here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30754

Comment: When I run that command on Debian machine I don't get any information, the behaviour is normal. I also tried every suggestions from that page and nothing worked. I updated the question posting the complete trace error.